# submitting form to controller@store

Tags: forms, controller, laravel-5.5

laravel 5.5 
 voyager 1.0

i'm trying to submit a form to a controller with :

```
<form class="" action="FeedController@store" method="post">
    <div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
        <input id="title" type="text"  name="title" value="" required autofocus>
        <label for="title" class="col-md-4 control-label">title</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
        <textarea id="description" type="textarea"  name="description" value="" required autofocus></textarea>
        <label for="description" class="col-md-4 control-label">description</label>
    </div>
    <input class="mui-btn btn-primary pull-right " type="submit" name="" value="submit">
</form>
```

within **FeedController**:

```
/**
*@param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function store(Request $request){

    $data = ReportDatum::create([
        'owner_id' => auth()->id(),
        'title' => request('title'),
        'description' => request('description')
    ]);
    return test;
}
```

and in the routes:

```
Route::resource('feed', 'FeedController');
```

(and/or depending on what I'm trying)

```
 Route::post('store', 'FeedController@store');
```

what I'm i missing to correctly submit the form?

**I'm not using laravelCollective forms**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `csrf_field()`. Try adding it after the `<form>` tag.

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf

Comment: right, thanks. it looks like laravelCollective forms adds csrf protection without having to specify but because i wasn't using laravelCollective forms you have to call the csrf middleware. that's where the confusion came from i think.

Answer (score 1):

You should define route at first then it will works: 
Resource controller routing

```
Route::resource('feed', 'FeedController');
```

or specific simple routing

```
Route::post('feed', 'FeedController@store');
```

Comment: this shows the form page but on submitting the form i get 'The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again.' the url is correct, it seems like the controller isn't functioning

Comment: I added more info to my question, your Answer is a step in the right direction. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Same error here. I've commented the line `\Greazy\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class` which stays in `app/Http/Kernel.php` and the post method worked in Postman, however it does not work when invoked on the form.